# Restart windows services sequentially with sleep - Ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have a requirement where I need to Restart a set of windows services on a set of hosts sequentially with 60 seconds between service start.  Appreciate your help

Order of Services

1. Polling Agent Service

> ```
>  wait 60 seconds then start 2) Memcached 
>  wait 30 seconds then start 3) watcher
> ```

Comment: what have you tried so far? is that throwing an error? have you looked at the `win_service` module? you mat benefit to read this post about [asking in SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `loop_control` with `pause` (*in seconds*).
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_loops.html#pausing-within-a-loop

One disadventage in your case is, that the pause time is the same with each loop, and not dynamically.

```yaml
- name: restart fluent-bit
  ansible.windows.win_service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: restarted
  with_items:
    - Polling Agent Service
    - Memcached
    - watcher
  loop_control:
    pause: 60 # 60 seconds after each item
```

Comment: thanks you for the sample code.  I would like to pause for only one item (watcher service) and not for all

Answer (score 0):

For linux systems, I do the following:

```yaml
- name: restart a service one by one, w 60 in between
  shell: systemctl restart my_service ; sleep 60
  throttle: 1
  args:
    warn: false
```

I assume you can apply the same logic same for windows systems, w `sleep/ping/timeout` and [`win_command`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/windows/win_command_module.html)